# TypeError: must be real number, not c_ulonglong

Tags: python, wmi, ctypes, win32com

I'm trying to control my laptop fan speed using WMI in python. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setspeed-method-in-class-cim-fan) says the input is uint64:

> ```
> uint32 SetSpeed(
>    [in] uint64 DesiredSpeed
> );
> ```

This is my python code:

```py
import wmi
from ctypes import c_uint64, c_double, c_ulong, c_size_t

c = wmi.WMI ()
cim_fan = c.CIM_Fan()
fan_speed = c_uint64(4000)
cim_fan[0].SetSpeed(fan_speed)
```

But it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AliEnt\Desktop\Athena Codes\control_fan\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    cim_fan[0].SetSpeed(fan_speed)
  File "C:\Users\AliEnt\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\wmi.py", line 440, in __call__
    parameter.Value = arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 686, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
TypeError: must be real number, not c_ulonglong
```

I tried every other types but no chance. What does it mean by saying *real number*?

Comment: Does your laptop support to set the fan speed? For example, mine doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does. It's Asus TUF and it has a software named Armoury Crate which you can choose between silent mode and turbo mode but it is so buggy and it sometimes forgets to turns the fans on and my CPU cores temp goes to 95°C! None of the fan control programs support my laptop so I want to control it by myself.

Comment: It is obvious that implementing such a method is not easy task on your own. Although not sure, Armoury Crate could have registered a class that implements the `SetSpeed` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a real *Python* number. No need to pass a `ctypes` type:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
cim_fan = c.CIM_Fan()
fan_speed = 4000
cim_fan[0].SetSpeed(fan_speed)
```

Comment: Using python number throws another error: `wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemObjectEx', 'This method is not implemented in any class ', None, 0, -2147217323), None)>`

Comment: Sounds like the call isn’t supported, but using a Python number is correct

Comment: Changed the question title

Comment: @AliEnt please ask a new question instead of changing an existing one. It invalidates the existing comments and answers.

Comment: I wanted to delete the question but it warned me it's better not deleting a question with answer and it may block me from further asking. And the previous question is wrong, I cannot keep it so I updated the question and notified that I changed the title.

Comment: @AliEnt the previous question wasn’t wrong. You wanted to know how to pass the parameter correctly. I answered that. Accept it and ask the new question.

Answer (score 0):

"real number" is synonym of "float". Try this:

```
import wmi
from ctypes import c_foat

c = wmi.WMI ()
cim_fan = c.CIM_Fan()
fan_speed = c_float(4000)
cim_fan[0].SetSpeed(fan_speed)
```

Comment: I've already tried `c_float` but throws `TypeError: must be real number, not c_float`